# How to convert Bitmap image to Base64PNG string in monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Hi i want to convert bitmap image to base64png format i tried using the following code.i don't think the code works good enough.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Bitmap immagex = signature;
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
immagex.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, baos);
 byte[] b = baos.ToArray();
 String Base64Encodestring = Base64.EncodeToString(b, Base64.Default);
```

Comment: "i don't think the code works good enough" - in what way? Does it work, but too slowly? Does it not compile? Does it compile but throw an exception? Stack Overflow is about answering *concrete problems* - this is far too vague. (I'd personally use `Convert.ToBase64String` rather than the Android API, but that's an entirely different matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this would do the trick.

```
     string tempBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

Goodluck.